# rbind data frames which are made by user-defined function

Tags: simulation, rbind

I create an user-defined function which return 67*348 data frame, and each elements in this data frame are made randomly. I define this function name as data.generating(...) (My goal is to create simulation datas, and merge it)

I am hoping to make a lot of data frame by using this function, and rbind these data...(about 10,000 times)

I tried to use 'for' loop, but it takes long times to get a result. 
Below is trimmed version of my script.

```
new_test_case<-data.frame()
for (j in 1:10000) {
 new_test_case<-rbind(new_test_case, data.generating(j)
}
```

I need your help for searching right approach. 
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (MVCE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question and chances to get an answer.